# Generate Keytool Object from CSR

Tags: certificate, keystore, public-key-encryption, sha, csr

I have to develop an application which uses another application for generating a CSR. After generating the CSR I have to provide this CSR along with a SHA256 hash of the public key to a CA. The problem is the application which generates the CSR doesn't generate the hash.

How do I generate the hashcode?

Can I create a keystore object using this particular CSR and then extract the hash from it?

Or can anyone suggest any other technique?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some details like what language you are developing in, if you need to do this programmatically or if command line OpenSSL is an option.

You can do this with the following OpenSSL command lines (I'm sure there is an equivalent way to do this with the OpenSSL C libraries).

```
# Extract public key from CSR
openssl req -noout -in my.csr -pubkey > pubkey.pem

# Convert public key to DER format
openssl rsa -in pubkey.pem -outform der -out pubkey.der

# Take the SHA256 hash of the public key
openssl dgst -sha256 pubkey.der
```